# Flutter DropdownSearch height

Tags: android, flutter, dart, widget, dropdown

[image dropdownsearch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWHy8.png)

Welcome , Is there any way to change the height of DropdownSearch widget

it's height is very big , putting it in container or sizedbox with height not working

```
DropdownSearch<String>(
                    
                    dropdownBuilder: (context, selectedItem) {
                      return Text(
                        selectedItem ?? "",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 104, 13, 2), fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                      );
                    },
                    popupProps: PopupProps.modalBottomSheet(
                      showSelectedItems: true,
                      fit: FlexFit.loose,
                    ),
                    items: itemsAPIwithAllSaf,
                    dropdownDecoratorProps: DropDownDecoratorProps(dropdownSearchDecoration: dropdownDecoration.copyWith(labelText: 'الصف')),
                    onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                      //selectedValueSafAPI = newValue!;
                  
                      setState(() {
                        selectedValueSafAPI = newValue!;
                        //ClearData();
                      });
                    },
                    selectedItem: selectedValueSafAPI.toString(),
                  ),
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.